# Electric Current Based Shape-Memory Alloy

Tags: materials, metallurgy, electrical, alloys

Would it be possible to create a piece of metal, made out of an alloy or combination of alloys, that undergoes a shape-memory-esque change in structure in reaction to an electric current? Could it also react differently depending on the type or orientation/direction of the current?

Ex:
A wire that, when electricity is passed through it one way, conracts/coils but extends when the currents flows in the opposite direction.

+__________- contracts
-__________+ expands

Comment: Get a two way alloy wire, run current through a segment enough to heat it up. It will transform. Shut off current and it will transform back on cooling. Can that work? I am not aware of any electromechanical alloys. Maybe someone else will know more.

Comment: @wwarriner I never thought about that, but yes, I am looking for an electromechanical alloy. Thank you for the comment though!

Comment: Go to Google Scholar and search "solid state electromechanical actuators". Strain levels of up to 1.7% have been realized in labs. Crystal orientation matters, so mechanisms can have limited freedom, but a huge number of degrees of freedom. I think some of the tiny centipede robots have used solid state electromechanicals for leg drives. Most materials seem to be ceramics or polymers.